# Go server hangs after sending INT signal

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "html"
    "os/signal"
    "os"
)

func main() {
//INT signal handling
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    go func() {
        for range c {
            log.Println("GOT SIGNAL!")
            return

        }
    }()
//INT signal handling

    http.HandleFunc("/bar", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

After pressing CTRL-C it hangs (server keeps working). But if you comment block between "INT signal handling", it finishes fine. 
Could you please explain this behaviour? It's obvious that http server can be created and started explicitly in separate goroutine and gracefully terminated there. But in general the question is how to explain behaviour from this code snipped, why http does not stop if there is new channel that handles SIGNTERM.
Thank you!

Comment: Your return in the INT handler only returns from the go routine that it is in. The problem is that your program now does not use the default behavior of terminating on receiving INT. Instead it calls your handler. The handler however does not stop your program. Add a `os.Exit(0)` in the handler if you want the program to stop. If this works for you I will make it an answer and you could check it as correct.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! But why does it work if no signal.Notify is defined? Could you please point me to the some "default behavior of terminating on receiving INT". Should i always call is.Exit if i handle SIGNTERM signal?

Comment: I now created a proper answer since it seem that was the problem. The thing is that by default all programs handle INT by exiting the application. Only a special mechanism defined in the `signal` package lets you change this by utilizing the appropriate OS specific system calls. By hooking into this you deactivate the default behavior in favor of handling the signal yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your INT handler you do not quit the program yourself.

If you install a signal handler for INT the default behavior of the program on receiving a Ctrl+C, which is quit the program, is not done. Instead the program now handles it by calling your INT handler code instead so if you want to exit your program, call `os.Exit(0)` in the loop.